Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9, Wi-Fi, and a certificate
My workplace uses NPS on Windows Server for Wi-Fi authentication: Windows users authenticate as dept\first.last as if logging into Windows, and it works.
Using my personal Android phone, I successfully connected to our Wi-Fi with the following:

PEAP
MSCHAPV2
CA Certificate: AAACertificateServices.crt
Domain: dept.ad.example.edu
Identity: dept\first.last
Anonymous Identity: blank

I'm now trying to connect to our Wi-Fi from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9. This is a fresh install of a workstation with GUI, and yes, I have wpa_supplicant installed. Using the GNOME Wi-Fi settings, I do this:

Wi-Fi Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: Protected EAP (PEAP)
Anonymous identity: blank
Domain: dept.ad.example.edu
CA certificate: Exact same AAACertificateServices.crt used successfully with Android
PEAP Version: Automatic
Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2
Username: dept\first.last
Password: my password

...and it doesn't work. The NPS server returns:

winlog.event_id: 6273
winlog.event_data.ReasonCode: 16
winlog.keywords: Audit Failure
winlog.event_data.ProxyPolicyName: Use Windows authentication for all users
winlog.event_data.Reason: Authentication failed due to a user credentials mismatch. Either the user name provided does not map to an existing user account or the password was incorrect.

We're pretty sure it's a certificate issue. I guess my biggest questions are:

Has anyone ever gotten such a setup to work successfully?
If so, which certificate--and which format certificate--is the GNOME Wi-Fi setup expecting?

Thanks!

The credential mismatch is kinda a clear error, did you tried using the firt.last@DOMAIN, or first.last@email.com to login ?

I've been using the exact same username I used from my Android phone to connect: dept\first.last; that is, domain\username.

Yet, "domain\username" is an ancient scheme dating back to NT4; try using modern UPN as yagmoth555 suggsted. Ask your AD admin about the correct suffix.

Thanks! I'm now trying "first.last@dept.ad.example.edu". I'm not getting in, but let me go check the RADIUS server logs to see what they have to say.

...and it went nowhere. I've tried DOMAIN/username, domain/username, domain\usermame, and username@domain.ad.example.edu

How I fixed this:
Wi-Fi security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: protected EAP (PEAP)
Domain: dept.ad.example.edu
No CA certificate is required
PEAP version: Automatic
Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2
Username: dept\first.last

The solution: I was NOT to supply a certificate.
Now for the fun part: this does work in RHEL 8, but does not work in RHEL 9. Does anyone have any ideas on this?
